# How to unit test a component that has a ref prop

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

How do you unit test a component that has a ref prop ? i'm getting this error

> ● Should render  › should render
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot add property current, object is not extensible
> ```

I looked at another question [Unit testing React component ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879176/unit-testing-react-component-ref), but there is no solution for that question.

this is the test

**CommentList.test.tsx**

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import React from "react";
import { CommentListComponent as CommentList } from "./CommentList";
import { render, getByText, queryByText, getAllByTestId } from "@testing-library/react";

const props = {
    user: {},
    postId: null,
    userId: null,
    currentUser: {},
    ref: {},
    comments: [
        {
            author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png", bio: null },
            comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfs",
            createdAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            gifUrl: "",
            id: 520,
            postId: 28,
            updatedAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            userId: 9,
        },
        {
            author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png", bio: null },
            comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfs",
            createdAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            gifUrl: "",
            id: 519,
            postId: 27,
            updatedAt: "2020-05-27T14:32:01.682Z",
            userId: 10,
        },
    ],
    deleteComment: jest.fn(),
};
describe("Should render <CommentList/>", () => {
    it("should render <CommentList/>", () => {
        const commentList = render(<CommentList {...props} />);
        expect(commentList).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

This is the component.

**CommentList.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, Ref } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import OurSecondaryButton from "../../../common/OurSecondaryButton";
import CommentListContainer from "../commentListContainer/commentListContainer";

function CommentList(props: any, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<Number>(2);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [showLessFlag, setShowLessFlag] = useState<Boolean>(false);
    const the_comments = props.comments.length;
    const inc = showMore as any;
    const min = Math.min(2, the_comments - inc);
    const showComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inc + 2 && inc <= the_comments) {
            setShowMore(inc + 2);
            setShowLessFlag(true);
        } else {
            setShowMore(the_comments);
        }
    };
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };

    const showLessComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMore(2);
        setShowLessFlag(false);
    };
    const isBold = (comment) => {
        return comment.userId === props.userId ? 800 : 400;
    };
    // show comments by recent, and have the latest comment at the bottom, with the previous one just before it.
    const filterComments = props.comments
        .slice(0)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const date1 = new Date(a.createdAt) as any;
            const date2 = new Date(b.createdAt) as any;
            return date2 - date1;
        })
        .slice(0, inc)
        .reverse();

    const showMoreComments = () => {
        return filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ));
    };
    console.log(ref);
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Fragment>
                <div data-testid="comment-list-div" style={{ margin: "30px 0px" }}>
                    {props.comments.length > 2 ? (
                        <Fragment>
                            {min !== -1 && min !== -2 ? (
                                <Fragment>
                                    {min !== 0 ? (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            View {min !== -1 && min !== -2 ? min : 0} More Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    ) : (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            Show Less Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    )}
                                </Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                    Show Less Comments
                                </OurSecondaryButton>
                            )}
                        </Fragment>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
            {showLessFlag === true ? (
                // will show most recent comments below
                showMoreComments()
            ) : (
                <Fragment>
                    {/* filter based on first comment  */}
                    {filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <CommentListContainer ref={ref} comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default React.forwardRef(CommentList) as React.RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, any>;
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it, i had to import

```
import CommentList from "./CommentList";
```

instead of

```
import { CommentListComponent as CommentList } from "./CommentList";
```

and do this to the props

```
 ref: {
     current: undefined,
 },
```

and comment/remove this line of code from commentList

```
// // prevents un-necesary re renders
// // export default React.memo(CommentList);
// // will be useful for unit testing.
// export { CommentList as CommentListComponent };
```